# pdf file in UIWebView : change the language of the page number infobox

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

When opening a pdf in a UIWebview, a little infobox appears on the top-left corner of the screen.
I would like the language of this infobox to be the same as the app language.
For the moment I only have it in french "1 sur 2", whereas I would need it in dutch "1 op 2"

Is it possible to force a language for this ? 
I've been changing the app language of the nsuserdefaults but it doesn't seem to impact this.
any help would be appreciated, thanks !

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Prince, is this a setting somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems this infobox uses the language of the device.
when changing the language in the NSUserdefaults, the app needs to be restarted before the uiwebview takes this into account.